# jQuery - .on doesn't work but .click does

Tags: jquery

having a major problem here and really can't get my head around it:

I have a bookmarklet -> using jQuery.

I can get the following to work:

```
$(".buttonbnitl162").click(function() {
```

absolutely fine.

```
$(document).on("click", ".buttonbnitl162", function() {
```

keeps giving me `'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'`

I am puzzled!

Any suggestions - or am I just being really REALLY thick here?

I am guessing I am in no-conflict mode but have tried the normal

```
jQuery(function($) {

});
```

So I am at a loss!

**EDIT**

```
var v = "1.11.1";

    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery < v) {
        var done = false;
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/" + v + "/jquery.min.js";
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
                done = true;
                initMyBookmarklet();
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    } else {
        initMyBookmarklet();
    }

    function initMyBookmarklet() {
        (window.myBookmarklet = function() {
            function getSelText() {
                var s = '';
                if (window.getSelection) {
                    s = window.getSelection();
                } else if (document.getSelection) {
                    s = document.getSelection();
                } else if (document.selection) {
                    s = document.selection.createRange().text;
                }
                return s;
            }
```

This is the code I use to pull in my own version of jQuery -> has worked fine in the past but yet again may be missing something simple?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Can you post your exact code (including function) for on?

Comment: I might be wrong, but by checking if there's actually another version lower than 1.11.1 in your script and if so, adding this one aswell, you'll end up having 2 jQuery libraries added, which is not the ideal. You could confirm that by inspecting the page and checking it.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes - but this is the problem with bookmarklets -> having two versions is indeed not ideal but is something that you CAN do and makes coding the bookmarklet a hell of a lot easier given its complexity! The current version of jQuery they use is 1.3!!!!

Comment: I see your point. And just now I noticed you're handling the conflicts.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, please don't use that. It is full of bugs. Use 1.7 directly instead

Comment: @GrahamRitchie, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: For anyone else having this problem - please just use version 1.7 instead of 1.11.1 -> seems to be a bug with .on in my particular circumstances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the info what you've provided it seems that you are using jquery < 1.7 version.

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) was only introduced in jQuery 1.7

Comment: Accepted your answer because your comment above actually sorted it - problem was indeed 1.11.1 -> changing to 1.7 immediately fixed the problem! What is the latest stable release - thought 1.11.1 was stable :-P